# Unable to create a table using query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that selects from this view.

```
CREATE VIEW
    CarRentalHistoryView
AS 
    SELECT
        c.vehNo,
        c.brand,
        c.dateRegistered,
        c.purchasePrice,
        c.rentalCost,
        c.condition as 'Before Condition',
        r.condition as 'After Condtion',
        r.dateRented,
        r.dateReturned,
        r.CustNo,cu.name,
        cu.id,
        cu.dateOfBirth
    FROM
        dbo.Car c
    Inner JOIN
        dbo.Rental AS r
    ON
        c.VehNo = r.VehNo 
    Inner JOIN
        dbo.Customer as cu
    on
        cu.CustNo = r.CustNo;
GO
```

This is the query that I am trying to run,

```
Select
    *
From
    dbo.CarRentalHistoryView
Where
    'Before Condition' != 'After Condition'
```

But the query runs fine even if this is the case

```
Select
    *
From
    dbo.CarRentalHistoryView
Where
    'Before Cion' != 'After Ction'
```

So my point being how can I ensure that I can get the results of vehicles that has different condition than before. TKS!

Comment: Never use single quotes for column aliases.  The proper escape characters in SQL Server are square braces.  I'm voting to close this, because this is a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote character literals. Square braces (`[]`) denote columns names. So your view creation should look like:

```
CREATE VIEW CarRentalHistoryView
AS 
SELECT c.vehNo, c.brand, c.dateRegistered, c.purchasePrice, c.rentalCost,
       c.condition as [Before Condition],
       r.condition as [AfterC ondtion],       
       r.dateRented, r.dateReturned, r.CustNo,
       cu.name, cu.id, cu.dateOfBirth
FROM dbo.Car c
Inner JOIN dbo.Rental AS r ON c.VehNo = r.VehNo 
Inner JOIN dbo.Customer as cu on cu.CustNo = r.CustNo ;
GO
```

Now, you can query it properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.CarRentalHistoryView
WHERE  [Before Condition] != [After Condition]
```

Comment: Tks, that was sorted out.